# Prove that $f(x)=x^3$ is continuous at $x=1$

Tags: calculus, continuity

The book I'm using proves this by finding an open interval $I$ with $1 \in I$ such that, for any $\epsilon >0$

$x \in I \implies |f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$

However, I chose to try it by using the definition of continuous function, as follows

$|f(x)-f(1)|< \epsilon \iff |x^3-1|<\epsilon \iff |x-1||x^2+x+1|< \epsilon \iff |x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+x+1}$

Because $x^2+x+1>0$.

Then, take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+x+1}$

Therefore,

$|x-1|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(1)|< \epsilon$

which means $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: No.  $\delta$ must be a constant and can not depend about the value of $x$ which is variable (although $\delta$ can, and usually must, depend on the value of $e$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your choice of $\delta$ does not depend only on $\varepsilon$, but also on $x$. You are also missing absolute values.

Instead, you should say that if $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(1)| < \delta( x^2+|x| + 1)$.

Now, if $|x-1|<\delta$ then (why is this?) $|x|< (1 + \delta)$. Thus, if we assume that $\delta \leq 2$ then we can say $|x| < 3$. Returning back to our inequality we get $|f(x)-f(1)|<\delta( x^2 + |x| + 1) \leq \delta( 3^2 + 3 + 1) = 13 ~ \delta$.

Now complete the proof by showing that if $\delta = \min( \frac{\varepsilon}{13},2)$ then for all $|x-1|<\delta$ we would have $|f(x)-f(1)|<\varepsilon$.

(Note, the choice, in the proof, to set $\delta\leq 2$ is arbitrary, you can rewrite the by proof by rather bounding $\delta\leq 1$ instead.)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the other responses, you need to re-consider the *order of operations* with respect to the specification for the limit of a function.  First any arbitrary $~\epsilon~$ is chosen.  Then, for this particular $~\epsilon,~$ a $~\delta(\epsilon)~$ is specified.

Then, assuming that you are checking whether

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a),$$

it must be proven that any $~x~$ in the neighborhood of radius $~\delta~$ around the point $~a,~$ will have its $~f(x)~$ value in a neighborhood of radius $~\epsilon~$ around $~f(a).~$  So, at the time that $~\delta~$ is specified, the pertinent values of $~x~$ are (in a sense) **unspecified**.

So, the pertinent values of $~x~$ to be *tested* depend on the value of $~\delta(\epsilon).~$ Therefore, it is invalid to simultaneously have the value of $~\delta(\epsilon)~$ *also* depend on the value of some specific value of $~x.$

You can however, also have $~\delta~$ depend on the arbitrary value of some **fixed** real number.

For example, a common strategy in $~\epsilon,\delta~$ demonstrations is to specify that

$$\delta = \min\left[ ~g(\epsilon), ~r ~\right],$$

where $~r~$ is some fixed positive number.

Answer (score 1):

I often say it, but it is easier to deal with problems where the variable goes to $0$ because our mathematical toolkit is more adapted.

Set $x=1+u$ with $u\to 0$

$$|x^3-1|=|(1+u)^3-1|=|3u+3u^2+u^3|<3|u|+3|u|^2+|u|^3$$

- Notice that with $\delta=1$ we get $|u|<1 \implies |u|^n<|u|$ for any $n$.

Therefore $|x^3-1|<3|u|+3|u|+|u|<7|u|$

- Now take $\delta=\varepsilon/7$ and $|u|<\delta\implies |x^3-1|<\varepsilon$

Just conclude by regrouping both conditions into $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{7})$

Answer (score 1):

Your choice for $\delta$ cannot depend on x. Consider, the following

We want to show that $f(x) = x^{3}$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Scratch: Let $\epsilon > 0$ then we will find $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-1| < \delta$ implies that $ |f(x) - f(1)| <\epsilon$.

So, we have that $|f(x) - f(1)| = |x^{3} -1| = |x-1||x^{2}+x+1|$. We need to find a bound for $|x^{2}+x+1|$.

Let $\delta \leq 1$, then $0 < x< 2$. Therefore, by the triangle inequality we have $|x^{2}+x+1| \leq |x^{2}| + |x| + 1 < 2^{2} + 2 + 1 = 7$

Hence, $|x-1||x^{2}+x+1| < 7\delta$. Notice that if we take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{7}$ then $|x-1||x^{2}+x+1| <7\delta = 7(\frac{\epsilon}{7}) = \epsilon$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0 $  then choose $\delta = min\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{7} \}$ ...
Try to continue from here. Let me know if you have any additional questions.